# Multiple hypothesis tests for the same hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I do not come from a statistical background, but I'm facing the following problem:

I have **one** hypothesis, but am able to come up with $n$ independent tests for. What is the right way to "combine" the individual tests?

Comment: How *independent*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate might give you some ideas

Comment: @Roy It will help if you can explain more. Are these tests on different data sets? Are you trying to combine a collection of p-values into a single p-value? (and it *might* potentially make some difference to an answer -- what test are you doing?)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica same dataset, but different attributes (I can guarantee that they are independent). I'm looking for the "best" way to use these p-value to make one decision.

Comment: How can you guarantee statistical independence? How are you defining "best"? (i.e. What are we optimizing?) (And again, what test are you doing?)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I'm doing several log-likelihood tests on (the same) two Gaussian populations. They are independent since each set of features in each test is orthogonal to the others. I do not know how do define "best" - this is why I posted this thread :)